# PHP Cookies, Sessions, and a form

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies, session-cookies

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton']))
{
    $cookie_name = $_POST['user'];
    $cookie_value = $_POST['user'];
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>cookie demo</title>
</head>



<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton']))
{
    $cookie_name = $_POST['user'];

    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
            echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' does not exist!";
    } else {
            echo "Cookie is named: " . $cookie_name . "<br>Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }

}
else
{


    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="user"/><br/>';
    echo "\n";

    echo '<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>';
    echo "\n</form>\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to learn how to do Cookies, so I created a simple input text box and a Submit button. I wanted the value of the cookie (the name submitted with the form) to show up before the form if there was a cookie present, otherwise solely display the form. I am having some trouble here, is there something incorrect?

Comment: Cookies get replayed first a page request later. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` whenever something doesn't work.

Comment: An error would help. Do what @mario has suggested and post the error.

Comment: Does SubmitButton? I think you need to assign a value="something" for it to be sent.